# drawing smile face using fillArc

Tags: java, graphics2d

How do I get full smile face?

I am trying to draw a happy face with full mouth smile,
it is giving me results like a half moon.

How can I get result like the picture?

What code should I use ? 
I tried to draw a curved line but im very beginner i could not find a way to fill it.

[image: this should be the end result]

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Smiley  extends JFrame {

    // constructor sets window's title bar string and dimensions (full screen)
    public Smiley (){
        super( "Happy Face" );
        setSize( 1660, 1080 );
        setVisible( true );
    }

    public void paint( Graphics g ){

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(7));

        // call superclass's paint method
        super.paint( g );

        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillOval(500, 200, 400, 400);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillOval(520, 350, 100, 100);
        g.fillOval(780, 350, 100, 100);

        g2.setPaint(Color.black);

        g.drawOval(500, 200, 400, 400);

        g.fillArc( 100, 120, 80, 80,180 , 180 );
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to draw a curved line but i could not find a way to fill it.

Well you can't fill a single curved line.

I assume you mean you want to fill the white part of the mouth between the two curved lines.

You might be able to use a `GeneralPath`. It will allow you to combine multiple lines/curves into a single shape. Then you paint the shape and fill it.

So the basic code might be something like:

```
GeneralPath gp = new GeneralPath();
gp.moveTo(...); // starting point
gp.curveTo(...); // first curve
gp.moveTo(...); // reset back to starting point
gp.curveTo(...); // second curve
g2.setColor( Color.WHITE );
g2.fill( gp );
```